# Not being able to recognize that value is not in a string

Tags: python

I have been experimenting with Telepot to read messages in Telegram and I am trying to have the bot read a user message `msg['text']`. If I just print `msg['text']` it echo's the user's message, so I am trying to assign it to a variable `message` and then have the bot reply in a certain way if a specific string was in the user's message. Whatever I input, it always prints the `"Ack was found in the message"` even if `"Ack" or "ack"` **isn't** in the message. I have tried further specifying by making another if statement by saying

```
if 'ack' or "Ack" not in message:
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Ack not found")
```

instead of an `else`, but this will just now print both if statement strings with whatever I input. Below is the full code:

```
import sys
import time
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)

    message = msg['text']

    if 'ack' or "Ack" in message:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Ack was found in the messsage")

    else:
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Ack not found")


MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
print ('Listening ...')

# Keep the program running.
while True:
    time.sleep(10)
```

I am following this documentation here: https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#receive-messages

SOLUTION: Updated the code to the answer suggested by @mkrieger1

```
if message in {"ack","Ack"}:
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Ack was found in the messsage")

if message not in {"ack","Ack"}:
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Ack not found")
```

Comment: `if 'ack' or ...` is always true.

Comment: Even with "not in"?

Comment: Yes, no matter what you write for `...`.

Comment: `if 'ack' or "Ack" not in message:` is the same as `if 'ack' or ("Ack" not in message):`. Does this make it any clearer?